# How to change form fields' value before validation?

Tags: python, django, validation

I have an *FloatField* in my models.py that has to store (among other things) minutes, seconds and milliseconds. It's no biggie to store them in the format of *ss.ms*, but I have to provide a possibility to insert them via *ModelForm* in the format of *mm.ss.ms*.
Problem is, form validation disapproves of *mm.ss.ms* for *FloatField* and I'm struggling to find a workaround.

*_clean* functions are great, but run after the Django validations. How to clean data from form **before** it gets validated by Django?

## EDIT:

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Result(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    result = models.FloatField()
    rank = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

### forms.py

```
class AddResult(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ('result', 'rank', 'date')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.profile = kwargs.pop('profile', None)
        super(AddResult, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.label_class = 'form-label-div'
        self.helper.field_class = 'form-field-div'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-xs-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-xs-8'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(
                    'result',
                    css_class="col-xs-4",
                ),
                Div(
                    'rank',
                    css_class="col-xs-4",
                ),
                css_class="row",
            ),
            Div(
                Div(
                    'date',
                    css_class="col-xs-4",
                    css_id="date-picker"
                ),
                Div(
                    css_class="col-xs-4",
                    css_id="date-picker"
                ),
                css_class="row",
            )
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        result = super(AddResult, self).save(commit=False)
        if self.profile:
            result.profile = self.profile
        result.save()
```

PS! Originally I wrote that I had a problematic *IntegerField*, but that was some kind of a brain fart. We're talking about a *FloatField* of course. The main question remains the same.

Comment: [to_python()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/) is the first step in form validation

Comment: I don't think your database will approve it either, using an IntegerField.

Comment: why not use `TimeField` which stores all of that already except it also stores hours. `TimeField` also has advantages like being able to compare them directly in SQL, etc...  If you dont need hours, you can simply default that to 0 or something but still use `TimeField`

Comment: given both comments above, in case you decide to go for a custom field (DB/django model), see if [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects) helps

Comment: I would use another type of field! Honest to god. But the code and architecture are done already and this field stores much more than just time - it has to store also meters, points and whatnot else. Redoing models and fields would require bigger changes in code than I would like.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to use models forms instead use a forms.form and in your view before the ** form.is_valid() ** try to retrieve the form fields with the help of REQUEST method.
 May be this helps.

Comment: Can I not do that with _ModelForm_? As much as I've understood from my research I can retrieve uncleaned data but not change it before validating.

Comment: Can i have a look at your model.py and form plz... and exactly tell me what you wanna... may be it will help.